# Using the flip and filter functions in haskell on a list

Tags: haskell

a Haskell newby, so apologies if this is a rather basic question. I want to write a function which takes two lists of variables and returns the first with all variables from the second list removed from it. For example I want the following output

*Main> filterVariables ["y","z","a1","a2"] ["y","a1","a3"]

["z","a2"]

This what I have written so far:

```
type Var = String

data Term =
    Variable Var
  | Lambda   Var  Term
  | Apply    Term Term


variables :: [Var]
variables =  [l:[] | l <- ['a'..'z']] ++ [l:show x | x <- [1..], l <- ['a'..'z']]

--works but the wrong way around!!!
filterVariables :: [Var] -> [Var] -> [Var]
filterVariables lst = filter ( `notElem` lst)
```

I get the following ouput:

*Main> filterVariables ["y","z","a1","a2"] ["y","a1","a3"]

["a3"]

Could the flip function be used here?

When I write:

```
filterVariables lst = flip (filter ( `notElem` lst))
```

I get this error message:

```
Couldn't match type ‘[Var]’ with ‘[Var] -> c0’
      Expected type: [Var] -> [Var] -> c0
        Actual type: [Var] -> [Var]
    • Possible cause: ‘filter’ is applied to too many arguments
      In the first argument of ‘flip’, namely ‘(filter (`notElem` lst))’
      In the expression: flip (filter (`notElem` lst))
      In an equation for ‘filterVariables’:
          filterVariables lst = flip (filter (`notElem` lst))
```

How do I use flip correctly? Or can you suggest another method?

Comment: Why not simply write ``filterVariables items lst = filter ( `notElem` lst) items``?

Comment: There's also a library function, `Data.List.(\\)` which you can `flip` to your heart's content. Also `l:[]` = `[l]`.

Comment: Where would you place the \\?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `flip` function takes an argument function of two inputs. So if you want to flip the arguments to `filterVariables`, you have to `flip` it in a form that takes two arguments. In your version:

```
filterVariables lst = flip (filter ( `notElem` lst))
```

you have already accepted one argument, and only one remains to accept. We can fix this by first moving the `lst` argument to the other side of the equality:

```
filterVariables lst = filter ( `notElem` lst) -- original, accepts one more argument
filterVariables = \lst -> filter (`notElem` lst) -- now a function which accepts two arguments
filterVariables = flip (\lst -> filter (`notElem` lst)) -- flipped form
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be simpler to write this as:

```
filterVariables :: Eq => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
filterVariables items lst = filter (`notElem` lst) items
```

You can not `flip` on `` filter (`notElem` lst) `` since, `filter (`notElem`lst)` has type `[a] -> [a]`, and `flip` has type `flip :: (b -> a -> c) -> a -> b -> c`. This thus should mean that `[a] -> [a]` is the same type as `b -> a -> c`, but that implies that `[a]` and `a -> c` are the same type.

You can however make use of `flip` by implementing a point-free variant:

```
filterVariables :: (Foldable t, Eq a) => [a] -> t a -> [a]
filterVariables =flip (filter . flip notElem)
```

Indeed, here `filter . flip notElem` has type `filter . flip notElem :: (Eq a, Foldable t) => t a -> [a] -> [a]` since it is equivalent to `\xs ys -> filter (flip notElem xs) ys` or shorter `` \xs -> filter (`notElem` xs) ``, so we can then flip `xs` and `ys`.